# Fired Trigger doesn't add record in to QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

From my understanding, all triggers in `QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS` will be added to `QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS` after it has been fired. However, I found there still nothing inside `QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS` even those triggers in `QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS` existing and being deleted?

May I know when will the trigger be moved to `QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS`?

Comment: How long it takes to execute your job? The data is removed from `QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS` the moment the job is finished.

Comment: This is the really big problem because without any record from fired triggers we can not create any report or dashboard for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Not accurate, perspective result]

From my perspective (from clicking refresh until a trigger has been inserted into fired_triggers table and right before triggering and being deleted)

trigger data gets inserted into fired_triggers table right about 20seconds before being triggered [need more proof research] and finally gets deleted after trigger has finished.

and also QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS having no data is due to creating a job with .durable() settings to false. Since this setting makes a specific job dependant to triggers.

Sorry for my bad english. Hope this helped a little.